# ¿Cómo paso un parámetro a una función en C sin que se use punteros?

Tags: c, bucle-for, matrices

Estoy intentando pasar un valor (fila) a una función (calculoSumMatriz) para que mediante un recorrido simple con un *for* me haga la suma de todos los valores de una columna en un array determinado. El problema surge cuando me indica IntelliSense que se debe realizar con punteros ya que me lo están pidiendo sin punteros.

Adjunto el código por si pueden ver algo que pase por alto. Un saludo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TCOL 4
#define TFIL 4
int calculoSumMatriz(int v, int fila);

int main()
{
    int f, suma, v;
    int v[TCOL][TFIL] =
    {{0,1,2,3},
    {4,5,6,7},
    {8,9,10,11},
    {12,13,14,15}
    };
    printf("Introduce un numero de fila del 0 al 3: ");
    scanf("%d",&f);
    suma = calculoSumMatriz(v, f);
    printf("El resultado de la suma es %d",suma);
}

int calculoSumMatriz(int v, int fila)
{
    int i = 0, suma = 0;

    for (i = 0; i<=3; i++)
    {
        suma = suma + v[fila][i];
    }
    return suma;
}
```

Comment: ¿ Pero no decías que no podías usar punteros ?

Comment: @Juanjo en esta solución creo que no se están usando punteros, creo, así es como nos han enseñado a hacerlo en la carrera sin punteros

Comment: Pues deberías decirle a tu profesor o al que sea que revise lo que está enseñando. En `C`, un *array* decae automaticamente a puntero. Lo único, que el compilador obliga a que el tamaño coincida. Así se ven luego las cosas que se ven :-(

Comment: Okay, muchas gracias :-)

Comment: @fm_manueljesus00 te comento que la solución no va en la pregunta, por favor edita elimínala de ahi y publicala donde corresponde que es en la zona de respuestas. Saludos

Comment: @BetaM ya está arreglado, gracias por el aviso!! Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: He conseguido dar con el error, les indico a continuación la solución por si a otro usuario le ocurre lo mismo.

Comenzando por la declaración de la función *calculoSumMatriz* en vez de ser tipo int debe ser float. Así mismo, la variable **v** debe ser tipo float e indicar el tamaño de nuestra matriz mediante las variables globales definidas TFIL y TCOL.

En el main, de las primeras variables, hay que borrar la declaración de *v* y hacerla abajo pero siendo de tipo float. A su vez, hay que poner correctamente TCOL y TFIL ya que se encuentran colocados a la inversa.

Para concluir, en el comienzo de la función que declaramos al principio hay que ponerlo igual que en el prototipo. Tras esto, el código correcto es el que adjunto a continuación.

Felices fiestas y que tengan un buen día.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TCOL 4
#define TFIL 4
float calculoSumMatriz(float v[TFIL][TCOL], int fila);

int main()
{
    int f, suma;
    float v[TFIL][TCOL] =
    {{0,1,2,3},
    {4,5,6,7},
    {8,9,10,11},
    {12,13,14,15}
    };
    printf("Introduce un numero de fila del 0 al 3: ");
    scanf("%d",&f);
    suma = calculoSumMatriz(v, f);
    printf("El resultado de la suma es %d",suma);
}

float calculoSumMatriz(float v[TFIL][TCOL], int fila)
{
    int i = 0, suma = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<=3; i++)
    {
        suma = suma + v[fila][i];
    }
    return suma;
}
```